# How does 翻's 2021 meanings appertain to 羽?

Tags: etymology

I don't understand how 羽 (wings) relate to the 8 definitions of 翻 below. What's the semantic field of 翻? How does 羽 (wings) relate to 翻's semantic field?

[image]

Above is [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E7%BF%BB#). Below is *Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 199.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the "2021" in the title. At least I thought you meant the word had 2021 meanings! Then I notice it is in the title of many questions you asked. What is the point of that?

Comment: I think he is trying to stress the definitions of the words he quoted are from dictionaries published in 2021 (the latest) -- And I agree it is a piece of useless information.

Comment: @TangHo Close! Yes, I'm trying to stress that the definitions are quoted from dictionaries published recently, and that I'm comparing modern/contemporary meanings with old ones.

Answer (score 1):

Flying birds can easily roll (翻) in the air. 羽 is related to both bird and flying

翻飛 = flying and rolling (in the air)

roll--> turn/flip

Answer (score 0):

翻 is a phono-semantic compound (形聲字) composed of the phonetic 番 which sounds like "fan" and the semantic 羽, which means wings or feathers. As the other poster alluded to already, the meaning is connected with flying. The original definition was "to fly around" and only later adopted meanings like flip/turn over or translate something.

Citation:

王力 主編，2000《王力古漢語字典》，北京：中華書局，2007年重印。

Answer (score 0):

Per "汉典", the original meaning (本意) of "翻" was "fly (飛)". The feathers/wings (羽) on the right enable the birds to make turns, which was represented by "番" on the left.